# "Use X, not Y" in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, sentence-choice, active-voice

How to "switch" this sentence from the active voice to the passive one?

Active voice:

> Use X, not Y.

Passive voice, first version:

> It must be used X, not Y.

Passive voice, second version:

> X must be used, not Y.

To be honest, the second version looks very weird to me, but this is how Google and DeepL translates the original sentence from my native language.

Comment: Your intuition is better than Google.

Comment: Use X, not Y cannot be made "passive": It is an imperative. However, "X uses Y" can be made into a passive: **Y is used by X**.

Comment: It all depends what X and Y actually ***are***. If they're adverbs, for example, *It must be used carefully, not forcefully* is fine. If they're nouns, the form *Logic must be used, not brute force* is the way to go.

Comment: @Lambie So is it correct to say that "It must be used X, not Y" is a something like **pseudo**–passive voice?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica They are nouns. Something like "Use the rule 42, not the rule 31".

Comment: If X and Y are nouns, *"It must be used X, not Y"* is syntactically invalid.

Comment: There are some "pathological" contexts where *It must be [PP verb] X, not Y* is valid when X and Y are nouns (or at least, *something like* nouns), as in *It must be written "X", not "x".* But they're pathological cases, not particularly relevant to people learning English.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks. So it seems you disagree with mdewey? Or maybe Michael assumed that X and Y are adverbs.

Comment: @mdewey Mike, are you sure my intuition is **really** better? :-) X and Y are nouns and the sentence is actually something like _"Use logic, not brute force"_. FumbleFingers said that I should rephrase it as _"Logic must be used, not brute force"_; and _"It must be used logic, not brute force"_ is syntactically invalid.

Comment: I don't know what mdewey meant. But I'm pretty sure I know what *you're* getting at, so I'm pretty sure the relevant issue here is *What are X and Y?* As Lambie points out, it's usually pretty meaningless to ask how an *imperative* can be converted to passive voice. Perhaps it's relevant to consider the format of ***Let X be used, not Y***, but if that's what interests you then I'm not sure you've presented the issue very well.

Comment: Why would anybody want to do this? But _It must be used X not Y_ is not English.

Comment: This: It must be used X,not Y. is not grammatical. What is grammatical is: **X must be used, not Y**.

Comment: OK I have confused matters totally. I thought you were numbering the versions 1, 2, 3 so you preferred 2 but I now realise you meant 3. The other comments are correct. Sorry about the noise there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Use X, not Y” is active imperative, with an implied subject of “you”.  The passive imperative form would be:

- Let X be used, not Y.

Your rewrite, however, switches from imperative to present, so let us first look at the active present form:

- You must use X, not Y.

This makes the subject (you) and object (X) clear, and we can now easily change this to the passive present:

- X must be used, not Y.

Answer (score 1):

Use X, not Y. - Active

Let X be used, not Y. - Passive.

(See Also [English Grammar dot org](https://www.englishgrammar.org/changing-imperative-sentence-active-voice-passive/))